# symfony very very slow

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

When I do an symfony2 application, a website, the website is very slow. I don't understand why. Have you any tips to find why?

For example:

Login with FOS, it take 7 seconds. For open another page it takes 8 seconds. It's the same in my web-hosting server or in local.

Comment: You could use Symfony profiler to find the root cause of slowness

Comment: Check this presentation: [Effective Doctrine2: Performance Tips for Symfony2 Developers](http://fr.slideshare.net/marcinchwedziak/effective-doctrine2-performance-tips-for-symfony2-developers-33907944)

Answer (score 0):

1. you should enable cache extension required by Symfony2 i.e. `APC 3.0.17+ (or another opcode cache needs to be installed)`. Full documentation can be read here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html
2. Other tip is to use `app.php` i.e. production environment to avoid re-building symfony cache.
3. You can also enable Doctrine cache: [Read Doc](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html)